# Пипетка в фотошопе неправильно определяет цвет

Tags: photoshop

Пипетка в Фотошопе неправильно определяет цвет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сколько точек пипетка захватывает? (размер образца)

Comment: написано что "точка"

Comment: Тогда возможно, что проблема с прозрачностью слоя. Попробуйте поизменять её

Comment: непрозрачность 100%, градиента тоже нет...

Comment: Установлен цветовой профиль. Ищите там.

Comment: У меня нормально определяется. Сбрось все настройки.

Answer (score 3):

Эта проблема очень просто решается. Объясню на примере англ. версии (т.к. у меня такая стоит).

Когда выбираешь "пипетку" вверху, прямо под панелью файла, фильтров и т.д. есть несколько опций для самой пипетки. Там должно стоять только "Current Layer" ("только этот слой") а НЕ "All Layers" ("Все слои") или что то другое! Если стоит что то другое - исправьте на "Current Layer" (только этот слой) и пипетка станет брать цвет только с того слоя на котором вы сейчас работаете, а не через все слои!

Смотрите на картинку:

[image: решение проблемы с пипеткой и неправильным определением цвета в Фотошопе!]